# What are the options for a 3rd-World Passport Holder to extend a Class-C Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, visa-extensions

I'm a Philippine passport holder. I got my Class C Schengen Visa but I was only given 20 days. What can I do to extend it even just for 90 days (I know that's the max allowed for Schengen short-stay visa)? Can I extend it while already in Europe?

Comment: What is 3rd word supposed to mean in this context? What is a 3rd World Passport Holder? Is there a specific designation for all applicants coming for a developing country?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply to extend your visa while you're in a Schengen country, if your current visa is still valid.

However, you will not be successful unless there's a very serious reason, such as you becoming so ill that you cannot travel. If your visa was granted for 20 days, then the issuing country decided it should be enough, and your itinerary probably showed an intended stay of no more than 20 days. The [European Commission website](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_area_en) has a [Schengen FAQ](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/http%3A//ec.europa.euwhat-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs//frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) that states (Question 18):

> When applying for a visa extension, you must show that due to force majeure or for
>   humanitarian reasons or for serious personal reasons it is not possible for you to leave
>   the territory of Member States before the expiry of your visa or the authorized period
>   of stay